# C format printf(%Lf) have wrong result

Tags: c

I'm a beginner of C. When I use `printf` format `%Lf`, I got a wrong result. My code is like  below.

```
long double dip = 5.32e-5;

printf("%Lf can be written %Le\n", dip, dip);
```

And I got the result as below:

```
0.000000 can be written 3.172882e-317
```

I wrote my code in vs code + MinGW. Any mistakes in my code?

Comment: _"I got a wrong result"_ – what's wrong with the result / what did you expect instead?

Comment: dip = 5.32e-5. I think the result should be `0.000053 can be written 5.320000e-05`@Stefan

Answer (score 3):

It seems MinGW doesn't support `%Lf` format by default.

Adding `-std=c99` compiler option may get it work.

This code worked on my MinGW gcc 4.8.1 with `-std=c99` option (I didn't use vs code):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long double dip = 5.32e-5;

    printf("%Lf can be written %Le\n", dip, dip);
}
```

output:

```
0.000053 can be written 5.320000e-005
```

Comment: The latest MinGW-w64 builds don't have any issues, but of course you really can't tell if a user is using the original MinGW or not unless they specify.

Comment: Thank you very much! I use MinGW gcc 8.1.0 with `-std=c11`.I set the `-std=c99`, But I got the wrong result again. I'm not familiar with vs code, maybe there are other mistakes. Anyway, thank you very much! @MikeCAT